# Android: Making a sign in page with option to use app without registering/signing in

Tags: android, android-layout

This sign in page that I want to create will give the option to use the app without signing in or making an account. But when a user chooses to do this, the main page of the app will have a slightly different UI compared to when the user is signed in.

So my question is, should I make two separate activities and layouts, one for being signed in and the other when not signed in. Or should I just use one activity and write some logic that will switch out the different UI parts?

I'm thinking of going with the two separate activities and layouts since this seems more clearer and neater. But the other version uses less duplication of code. What would be the best practice in a situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different layouts won't be difficult, I think you are confused on how to switch the layout, because that will be the easiest way.

```
if(loggedIn){
setContentView(R.layout.loggedInLayout)

}else{
setContentView(R.layout.NotLoggedInLayout)
}
```

You will want to keep this code in your `onCreate()` method. Basically, it says:

```
If I'm logged in, lets use this layout

Otherwise [not logged in] lets use this other layout.
```

Either way, its almost the same java code, just slightly different layouts!

According to the dev docs:

> ...the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which
>   you can place your UI with setContentView(View)...

So to answer your question, switching the layouts will be best.

Let me know if this was helpful!

Comment: Yes this was very helpful. The only UI that is changing is the toolbar. So I guess I can have a boolean checking if user is signed in or not and then in `OnCreateOptionsMenu()`, look up that boolean and inflate the appropriate toolbar. For some reason I was thinking I would I need to make another Activity class. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ghost_Stark I'm glad I helped! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to create separate layout. To no repeat code you can make a mother class that extend Activity in put the code that will be same for each activity and extends your activity to ther mother class that extend Activity